# DocumentDB - Quantify bounded execution in stored procedure

Tags: javascript, performance, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have a DocumentDB stored procedure that does insert or update (not replace but rather reads and update existing document). The stored procedure does at most two operations:

1. query by Id and
2. either insert or update

The document is also not particularly large. However, every now and then I would get either time out (caused by bounded execution) or 449 (conflict updating resources, which is a transient error).

IMO this isn't a particularly taxing stored procedure but seems that I'm running to limitations already. I could do more work client side but I love the ACID guarantee in the stored procedure.

Is there any quantitative measure on bounded execution? I'm wondering if I'm simply doing things wrong or I have indeed hit limit of DocumentDB.

My stored procedure is a modified https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/update.js that takes in document instead of id. I'm using "$addToSet" in particular and the code looks like

```
function unique(arr) {
    var uniqueArr = [], map = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var exists = map[arr[i]];

        if (!exists) {
            uniqueArr.push(arr[i]);
            map[arr[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    return uniqueArr;
}

// The $addToSet operator adds elements to an array only if they do not already exist in the set.
function addToSet(document, update) {
    var fields, i;

    if (update.$addToSet) {
        console.log(">addToSet");
        fields = Object.keys(update.$addToSet);

        for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (!Array.isArray(document[fields[i]])) {
                // Validate the document field; throw an exception if it is not an array.
                throw new Error("Bad $addToSet parameter - field in document must be an array.");
            }

            // convert to array if input is not an array
            var newIds = Array.isArray(update.$addToSet[fields[i]])
                ? update.$addToSet[fields[i]]
                : [update.$addToSet[fields[i]]];

            var finalIds = unique(document[fields[i]].concat(newIds));
            document[fields[i]] = finalIds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

DocumentDB stored procedures must complete within 5 seconds. They are also limited by the provisioned throughput of the collection. If you have 5000 RU/s provisioned, then the stored procedure cannot consume more than 5000 * 5 RUs in total.

When a stored procedure reaches its execution time or its throughput limit, any request to perform a database operation (read, write, query) will receive a pre-emption signal, i.e. the request will not be accepted as a signal for the stored procedure to wrap up execution, and return to the caller. If you check for return code from each call, your stored procedure will never timeout. Here's a snippet showing how to do this (full samples are available at https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/):

```
var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(...) {
     // additional logic in callback
});

if (!isAccepted) {
   // wrap up execution and return        
}
```

Regarding `449`, this is a concurrency error that can be returned if your stored procedure attempts to perform a conflicting write. This is side-effect free and safe to retry on from the client. You can implement a retry until succeeded pattern whenever you run into this error.

Comment: Should they hit those bounded execution limits with just two operations? I know it consumes RUs, but could it be that all the RUs are consumed by other operations when this one runs?

Comment: @Aravind thanks for the additional info but something doesn't add up. Some additional background info 1) The environment is our development environment and this is a feature not yet enabled so I expect virtually zero traffic aside from developers 2) The collection is a partitioned collection with 2500 RU. Lastly, I've discovered that the timeout is from the select which is querying by id and partition key. This is quite unexpected

Comment: Just to note that we've since moved back to 2 REST call on client. 
#1 Query by id + partition key 
#2 Upsert

For #2 we are relying on optimistic concurrency as we don't expect that many collisions (it's a batch process). Happy to say that it seems to be very reliable and much faster than doing both op in stored proc. Nevertheless, still curious as to why I'm hitting the limits so early.